# How can I remotely access the desktop of android from Ubuntu?

Tags: android, remote-desktop, vnc

I can access the desktop of Ubuntu from android by running a vnc server on ubuntu and a vnc client on android.

How can I remotely access the desktop of android from Ubuntu?

If you recommend to run a VNC server on Android, does the VNC server have the same security issue that many VNC servers have? (When I run a VNC server on Ubuntu, to secure it, I have to use iptables to restrict its accessibility to the localhost (Ubuntu) and use ssh port forwarding to access the VNC server on Ubuntu from android )

Comment: Run a [VNC server app](https://www.pingzic.net/best-vnc-server-apps/).

Comment: Does it have the security issue that many VNC servers have? When I run a VNC server on Ubuntu, to secure it, I have to use iptables to restrict its accessibility to the localhost (Ubuntu) and use ssh port forwarding to access the VNC server on Ubuntu from android

Comment: Which of the five on that page are you referring to?

Comment: Any of the  free ones.